# How can give name for generate pdf using mpdf codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, mpdf, codeigniter-3

if anybody konws this,please help me.how to give name to pdf.
    i generated pdf using mpdf codeigniter. on click of a button the pdf wil be viewed. but how can give name for that pdf? it shows 1 on the top of the pdf.how can i give name to that pdf?
My controller

```
public function viewpdf($key,$option) {

     if($option=='1')
    {
        $searchdata['fetchproduct']=$this->b2bproduct_model->fetch_productdata1($key);

    }
    if($option=='2')
    {
        $searchdata['fetchproduct']=$this->b2bproduct_model->fetch_productdata2($key); 
    }
    if($option=='3')
    {
       $searchdata['fetchproduct']=$this->b2bproduct_model->fetch_productdata3($key); 

    }

    $html=$this->load->view('moderator/pdf_data', $searchdata,true);

        //this the the PDF filename that user will get to download
        $pdfFilePath = "shany.pdf";

        //load mPDF library
        $this->load->library('m_pdf');

       //generate the PDF from the given html
        $this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML($html);

        //download it.
        $this->m_pdf->pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, "I");   
      }
```

Comment: Show some (real) code, please.

Comment: @phaberest i put code here

Answer (score 2):

Use this code.

```
$mpdf=new mPDF();
$mpdf->SetTitle('My Title');
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<p>Hallo World</p>');
$mpdf->Output('filename.pdf');
```

Set the title for the document. The title is displayed at the top of the Adobe Reader screen when viewing the PDF file

Answer (score 0):

Use code as bellow

```
public function mypdf() {     
   $this->load->library('pdf');     
   $pdf = $this->pdf->load();     
   $html=$this->load->view('welcome_message',null,true);
   $pdf->WriteHTML($html);      
   // write the HTML into the PDF     
   $output = 'your_given_name.pdf'; //You can give a name of your generated pdf file or you can create it auto on timestamp by using $output = time().'.pdf'.
   $pdf->Output("$output", 'I');     
}
```

If you send data to view page then replace the **variable** with **null** in line 4.

For more details please see the tutorial from [here](http://advancetechtutorial.com/pdf-generate-in-codeigniter-using-mpdf/).

If you are interested on DOMPDF please see from [here](https://advancetechtutorial.blogspot.com/2015/09/pdf-generate-in-codeigniter-using-dompdf.html).